# I'm really close. How do I get one or the other? One must exist

Tags: regex

Been working on this regular expression in order to find a string that must be 6 in length.

```
^[a-zA-Z]([0-9]{5})?([0-9]{1,4}[*])?$
```

The problem is that I need to have either the wildcard format or the 5 digits. One of them must exist.

It must contain 1 character followed by 1-5 digits.
It may contain a wildcard * after 1 character and 1-4 digits.

As you can see in the EXAMPLE Image the 'b' is highlighted when it should not. All of the other highlights are correct.

[image: Examples of matches and non matches]

Comment: You may try: `^[a-zA-Z]([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{1,4}\*)$` or look at: https://regex101.com/r/xna13w/1

Comment: `([0-9]{5})?` and `([0-9]{1,4}[*])?` are optional patterns that follow one another, if you want to match one or the other all you need is to place them in an *obligatory* (non-)capturing group ``([0-9]{5}|[0-9]{1,4}[*])``.

Comment: Someone had posted this, but then deleted it, which was perfect: ^[a-zA-Z](?=.)(?:[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{1,4}[*])?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone else posted the answer but then deleted it.

Here it is:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?=.)(?:[0-9]{5}|[0-9]{1,4}[*])?$
```

Results are correct: 
[image]

Comment: Remove the lookahead `(?=.)`  and make the non capture group mandatory (remove the `?` at the end)

Comment: @Toto thank you for the update. That works as well. I'll use it and remove the excess syntax.